# Как проверить пароли в форме перед отправкой?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Хочеться реализовать, но в JS не силен. Помогите.
Суть задачи в том, что как только пользователь ввел неверный (проверочный) пароль, поле для ввода сразу засветилось красным цветом, и рядом вывелось сообщение о некоректном вводе?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#repPass').change(function() {
            var pass = $("#pass").val();
            var pass_rep = $("#repPass").val();

            if (pass != pass_rep) {
                $("#repPass").css('border', 'red 1px solid');
                $('#errorBlock').html('Пароли не совпадают');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="errorBlock"></div>
```

Введите пароль: `<input type="password" id="pass" />`. Повторите пароль: `<input type="password" id="repPass" />`.

Comment: можешь также в строке `$('#repPass').change(function() {` сменить change на keyup тогда при вводе пароль при каждом нажатии на клавишу будет происходить проверка на правильность совпадения пароля

Comment: Подскажите, на примере как вставить его в форму отправки. А то вроде все сделал, а она даже не реагирует?

Comment: навряд автор вопроса имел ввиду решение подобного рода, так как он указал что не силен (скорее всего имелось в виду послать ajax-ом запрос на сервер если пароль неверен вернуть результат и подсветить поле) так как пароли в js никто не хранит))) разве что хеши и то...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {$("#pass, #pass2").keyup(validate);});

function validate() {
  var pass1 = $("#pass").val();
  var pass2 = $("#pass2").val();

  if (pass1 == pass2) {$("#sw").text("Пароли совпадают");
  } else {$("#sw").text("Пароли не совпадают");}
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]